# Massive Memory Usage for Docker on WSL2, but not for Docker on Native Linux

Tags: linux, docker, docker-for-windows, wsl2

I'm currently building cross-compilers via [crosstool-NG](https://crosstool-ng.github.io/) in Docker images to simplify integration testing for a variety of low-level libraries. My laptop, running native Fedora (x86_64, 16GB RAM, i7 @2.20GHz, Docker version 20.10.6), can build the toolchain with the memory rarely exceeding 5% of the total (monitored via [glances](https://github.com/nicolargo/glances)).

However, since I frequently use my laptop for development work, and therefore would like to limit CPU usage on it, I've considered using my desktop, running Windows 10 (x86_64, 16GB RAM, i7 @3.60GHz Docker version 19.03.6), to build the images using Docker for Windows on WSL2. However, quickly the entire remaining memory is used up by the Docker container (peaking where the total memory usage on my CPU was at 95-96%, and it was peaking well above 9-10GB, monitored via [glances](https://github.com/nicolargo/glances)), and starts using swap memory. This is monitored via the `vmmem` process, which encompasses all virtual machines.

I've tried to remedy the situation using a `.wslconfig` file, as follows:

```
[wsl2]
memory=6GB
processors=5
```

Although the config file does work, it merely caps out at 6GB of memory before aggressively swapping memory. The baseline memory for the Docker engine is ~2GB of memory, which still leaves ~4-12GB of memory unexplained. I do not have a Linux image associated with WSL2 (only a Ubuntu image with WSL1), however, since newer Docker versions require WSL2, I figured this wouldn't be an issue.

Is there any way to reasonably build cross compilers on Docker for Windows? Do I need to rent a cloud computing instance? Any feedback, or help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: 5% of 16 GB is 800 MB. I _very much_ doubt this is accurate. A desktop with a browser requires that much doing nothing. Compiling, especially linking, can require a lot more memory. You may also be confusing memory usage of the Docker WSL virtual machine with memory usage of the Docker container.

Comment: @DanielB There only way to monitor that is via the `vmmem` process on Windows. Also, I only included the memory that was being used by the Docker image and processes, which went from a baseline of ~34% to ~38% on Linux. So, this doesn't include the desktop environment, browser, or Sublime Text, or background processes, for either case. Even if it did, it doesn't explain the discrepancy. I was somewhat surprised by the extremely low memory usage, since normally natively compiling uses much, much more but that were my figures.

Comment: Even if we assume 15% on Linux, which is well above what I observed, it still doesn't explain the massive, massive discrepancy between the two. The scripts also are relatively straightforward:

1. Install dependencies via apt-get. 2. Download latest crosstool-NG via wget. 3. Untar, make, and install crosstool-NG. 4. Build crosstool-NG with 5 parallel jobs. 5. Build the cross-compiler with 5 jobs. 6. Remove dev dependencies.